# How to split video into frames using OpenCV Java?

Tags: java, opencv, video

I'm working on a project to analyze the motion of an object across a video, and I want to split the video into `BufferedImage` to analyze them frame by frame. Is OpenCV the best library for doing this? If so, how would the code look (I looked on their website but couldn't find it in the documentation). I'm new at this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture allows to read video frame by frame.

Here is example of usage: 
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture